# Subdivided mesh cube with texture

Tags: mesh

How can I create a subdivided *cube* with the texture shown on the example:

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to an _Image texture_ to wrap around a cube? Hand painting it could take a long time.

Comment: My texture is created with cycles render , is not image texture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option to achieve this look would be to use a musgrave texture as the factor of two diffuse shaders. For this example, a quick search for 'grid image' gave me an image to use for slight displacement, and to keep things simple as the wireframe node will give triangles, and freestyle didn't look too good either.

This is the image used for the grid:

[image]

The node setup is as follows, note that the musgrave is connected to the *object* output of the texture coordinate node, and the mapping node to the *UV* output as the cube is uv unwrapped.

[image]

Play with the *scale* on the musgrave texture to get a look that you like, likewise with your grid texture in the mapping node.

This should give you a starting point, hope it helps. Finished result:

[image]

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help @saded.

Comment: Thank's, for the image grid, are you send me?